# Split column data, add data in, remerge together

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, split

I have a text file with two columns (tho perhaps its just tabs?). One of the column has data that looks like this: TC012950_CDS_3428_4122
The first number is the TC#, second CDS, third starting location, fourth ending location. 
The other column has one value like this: 11.93631

I have another text file that contains the chromosome information split by tabs:

ChLG10  protein_coding  mRNA    3428    5582    .   -   .   TC012950

My overarching goal is to eventually incorporating the Chromosome Name (ChLG10) into the column of the first file so it looks like: 
TC012950_ChLG10_3428_4122
with the second column still containing its original value.

I've tried putting the data into an array or dataframe but then then I have a hard time splitting the first column. I keep getting errors that say replacement has 0 rows and such. Thus, I was hoping maybe someone on here could point me in the right direction.

How can I split that first column into multiple columns by using the _? Is there a way to split them into tabs perhaps?
After that, I need to match each row to its corresponding row in the other data so I can put the Chr Location column in between the TC# and CDS column. Once that is in the right location, then I need to merge all the columns back together and be separated by a _. I'm thinking if I did something with tab, then I would just replace the tab with the _ again? Any advice or help is welcome. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: There are endless ways of doing what you're asking, but we need some data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression in the `sub` function to put the desired value into the first column. I just faked your data with two data frames.

```
dat1<-data.frame(V1='TC012950_CDS_3428_4122', Value='11.93631', stringsAsFactors=F)
print(dat1)
                  V1    Value
1 TC012950_CDS_3428_4122 11.93631

dat2<-data.frame(V1='ChLG10',V2='protein_coding', V3='mRNA')
print(dat2)
      V1             V2   V3 
1 ChLG10 protein_coding mRNA

# loop over the rows in the data.frames
for (i in 1:nrow(dat1)) {
    dat1$V1[i] <- sub('_[A-Za-z0-9]+_',paste('_',dat2$V1[i],'_',sep=''),dat1$V1[i])
}
print(dat1)
                     V1    Value
1 TC012950_ChLG10_3428_4122 11.93631
```

The arguments to `sub` are as follows:

1. pattern to look for—one or more digits or letters between two
   underscores; the word character class (`\\w`) won't work in this case, because it includes the underscore
2. string with underscores and the desired code from the second file
   between them;
   `paste` just concatenates and uses an empty string
   separator
3. target string to modify (first column of second file)

`sub` will only replace the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

One way of splitting a column into multiple columns is via `tidyr::separate`. After separate, you can unite them again using `tidyr::unite`.

```
library(tidyr)
df = data.frame(A = c("1_2_3","4_5_6"))
df2 = df%>%separate(col="A",into=c("A","B","C"),sep = "_")
```

Output:

```
  A B C
1 1 2 3
2 4 5 6
```

You can then unite columns in any order as follows:

```
df2%>%unite(col="new",B,C,A,sep="_")
```

Output:

```
    new
1 2_3_1
2 5_6_4
```